# pausing and resuming webkitSpeechRecognition without losing microphone permissions

Tags: javascript, webkit, speech-recognition

I am building a voice controlled interface for a video playlist application.

The trouble is that the voice controller picks up the sound of the video, which can lead to false positives. I would like the voice controls to only be available during the breaks between clips.

I can see that pausing and resuming webkitSpeechRecognition has a start and stop method. The trouble is that when an instance of the webkitSpeechRecognition class is stopped, it needs to ask for permissions again to resume. Is there a built in way around this, like a pause method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSL/HTTPS to avoid having to ask for permission each time you want to access the microphone. [Reference](http://jensarps.de/2013/03/07/using-voice-commands-to-control-your-game/)